# Regular expression matches more than expected

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

Given is the following python script:

```
text = '<?xml version="1.24" encoding="utf-8">'
mu = (".??[?]?[?]", "....")
for item in mu:
    print item,":",re.search(item, text).group()
```

Can someone please explain why the first hit with the regex `.??[?]?[?]` returns `<?` instead of just `?`.

My explaination:

- `.??` should match nothing as `.?` can match or not any char and the second `?` makes it not greedy.
- `[?]?` can match `?` or not, so nothing is good, too
- `[?]` just matches `?`

That should result in `?` and not in `<?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason `o*?bar` matches `oobar` in `foobar`. Even if the quantifier is non-greedy the regex will try to match from the first char in all possible ways, before moving on to the next.

First the `.??` matches an empty string, but when the regex engine backtracks to it, it matches `<`, thus making the rest of the regex match, without moving the start position of the match to the next character.

Answer (score 2):

Regex "greediness" only affects backtracking; it doesn't mean that the regex engine will skip earlier potential match points — a regex *always* takes the first possible match.  In this case, that means `<?` because it starts farther to the left than `?`.